# Interpreting geom_smooth() linear relationship outcomes in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing

I am trying to analyse any potential relationship between unemployment rate and three types of crime: anti-social behaviour, theft, and violence & sexual offences.

To do so, I plotted crime occurrences plus their smooth conditional means using a geom_smooth() for each type of crime.  On the same graph, I also plotted the unemployment rate.

Here's the output, which I am having a bit of a hard time to interpret:

[image]

The green smooth conditional mean, which refers to theft, is pointing downwards. Does this imply that there is a **negative** relationship between theft and unemployment rate? If so, why would theft fall so harshly like unemployment rate did from 02/2020 until 04/2020? After that, theft increased slightly again as unemployment rate skyrocketed in July-August.

To me, this seems like a fairly positive relationship.

Am I interpreting the geom_smooth() outcomes wrongly? This is not a coding question, I'd just like to understand how to read geom_smooth() linear relationship outcomes.

Or should I change the linear relationship with "loess" instead for a clearer visual output?

Here's the code if it helps:

```
 ggplot(mapping=aes(Date)) +
  ggtitle("Crime rate and unemployment rate relationship \nin regions with higher unemployment rate") +
  geom_line(aes(y = Crime_occurrences, colour = Crime),
            size = 1, data = cr_grouped) +
  geom_line(lwd = 1, mapping = aes(x = Date,
                                   y = rescale(Unemployment.rate, #needed to scale unemployment rate
                                               to = out_rangeH,
                                               from = in_rangeH),
                                   linetype = "Unemployment rate"),
            data = ur_grouped) +
  labs(linetype = "") +
  new_scale_color()+
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm',se=F,
              aes(x=Date,y = Crime_occurrences, group=1,
                  color="Anti-social behaviour"),
              lty = 6, data=smooth_antisocial)+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm",se=F,
              aes(x=Date,y = Crime_occurrences, group=1,
                  color="Theft"), 
              lty = 6, data=smooth_theft)+
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm',se=F,
              aes(x=Date,y = Crime_occurrences, group=1,
                  color="Violence and sexual offences"),
              lty = 6, data=smooth_violence)+
  labs(colour = "Smooth Conditional Means") + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "darkgreen", "blue3"))+
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2020-10-01"), by="1 month"),
               date_labels = '%m %Y') +
  #adds a second Y axis scaled for unemployment rate and names it accordingly
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = 
                       sec_axis(~ rescale(.x, to = in_rangeH, from = out_rangeH), 
                                name = "Unemployment Rate (%)")) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle =- 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Comment: This is a question probably best answered on Cross Validated. Anyway your linear trendlines simply means that there is a negative linear trend over time. But is doesn't tell you anything about whether this is related to the change in unemployment or not. If you want to study the relationship between Crime and Unemployment, then I would suggest to start with a scatter plot.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm still pretty new to all this. How would you suggest going around this? I tried changing both crime and unemployment rate from geom_line() to geom_point() but it's pretty hard to understand what's going on. Should I keep unemployment rate as a line and crime as a scatter plot?

Comment: You are regressing on **Date**, not on unemployment rate. Nothing can be said about that hypothetical relationship.

Comment: Q: How would you suggest going around this? A: put unemployment rate in the x axis and see. If it seems that there is a relationship, draw a regression line with `geom_smooth`. Oh, and fit models with `lm()`.

Comment: Yes because I meant to study that relationship over time, I assumed a line graph would be the most suitable way to do so. I could make a scatter plot with X = unemployment rate and Y = crime occurrences then?

Comment: Just changed it to a scatter plot and the relationship is much clearer! Somehow most crime occurrences are reported when unemployment rate is lower. One last question: should I draw a regression line for every crime type just like a did before in the line graph?